# TextView modifies Linearlayout proportions when using ellipsize

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm using ListView to display list of film. I used android:layout_weight to arrange each item, and I put 0.5 for my RelativeLayout, who contains 2 TextView : *ZoneName* and *FilmName*

[image]

**fragment1.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fond"
>

    <TextView
        android:text="En séléctionnant un des écrans ci-dessous, vous accéderai à des informations complémentaires sur les contenus qui sont en train de passer à l'écran."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/secondScreenInformationTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_select_screen"
        android:background="#26FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here my **item_select_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/screenTable"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img_screen_type"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title_screen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_title_screen"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:id="@+id/item_poster_miniature"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_triangle"
        android:id="@+id/item_img_triangle_select_screen"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's works well with short string, but I add android:maxLines="1" and android:ellipsize="end" to shortcut the String if necessary. But when it does, it extends  the width of my RelativeLayout, and my 3 imageView seem to reduced to compensate for the change.

I can fix that using maxWidth, but it will be no more dynamic.

Comment: have you tried using `android:maxLength="..."` to limit of text length when ellipsizing?

Comment: yes, it's like maxWidth, and I'm not sure it's a good solution if you wan't to adapt your screen to the user device (maybe you want show 10 letter on a large screen and only 4 or 5 in a small one) ?

Comment: it's not ideal solution. the right way to handle it would be specifying proper weight and width 0dp as the accepted answer says. if you did go with android:maxLength though, I would suggest defining char counts dynamically in dimens for each min screen width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with weights, always give `0dp` as the height or width for the children depending on the `orientation` and let the weight do the measurements.

So your `RelativeLayout`'s width should be 0dp, same for the rest. I am guessing thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the behaviour is quite expected.

You are using,

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

for your `TextView`. So it would try to **wrap its entire contents** and adjust its size accordingly.

As the content is large and it is ellipsized, the **TextView takes the maximum width available** to it to wrap all of its content and then ellipsize at the end.

So, **the solution is to,**

1) Either have a fixed width for the TextView and have ellipsize at end.

2) Or programatically truncate the contents to the length desired for a perfect layout rendering. You can also add ellipsize to the truncated string.

Both would have the same effect (its your choice) but **would never distort your layouts**.

Comment: Thanks you for this answer! Don't you think it could be a problem if you want to adapt your interface to several device with different size?

Comment: @gamerounet It should not be a problem. But instead of weights, (which is outdated) you can try PercentageRelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are also setting widths in dp which screw up weight, try setting them to 0dp

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_img_screen_type"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title_screen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_content_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_title_screen"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:id="@+id/item_poster_miniature"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_triangle"
    android:id="@+id/item_img_triangle_select_screen"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect too for my case, I just accepted Uday answer because it could help people on a similar case (without my code)